# Mail Merge with different attachment for each recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

Hey i found this question on [this Google product forums page](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/JMhPUFCT3TE) and i have the same question myself. have been trying to figure it out but cant get it working, anyone have any ideas? i also found the same mailmerge on http://veetrag.net/2011/01/25/mail-merge-in-gmail-with-attachment-support/

"Hello everyone,
I'm using the spreadsheet found on this site http://www.it4smallbusiness.co.uk/web-applications/google-mailmerge to do a mail merge.  It works great except that I want to be able to send a different attachment to each recipient.

For example, if on the "Data to be merged" sheet I could add a column that holds the attachment IDs and associates each attachment ID with the email address on the same row.

Say I have 50 PDF attachments.  I upload all of them to google docs and they will each have an ID.  This is the ID I would use.

I tried editing the script to achieve this but couldn't figure it out.  Any ideas?  Thank you!"

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your [second link](http://www.it4smallbusiness.co.uk/web-applications/google-mailmerge) and made a copy of of curiosity... It seems that what you want to do could be quite easy to achieve if you can deal with a part of the job being manual, i.e. getting the IDs of all the attachments you want to add.

It could also be possible to import these files and assign each of them to every email in a script but that would make the whole thing more complex.

Assuming you are ready to get the IDs you should add a 5th column in the "data to be merged" sheet (col F) and change the script as follows (I reproduce only the relevant part starting on line 70 :`function runMailMerge() {` )

```
function runMailMerge() {

  //set up the status column, so it's blank, and pink
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data to be merged"); //used later in updating the status box
  var totalRows=sheet.getMaxRows();
  var range=sheet.getRange(2,1,totalRows,1);
  var failed=false;
  range.clearContent();
  range.setBackgroundRGB(230,153,153);
  if (totalRows>25) Browser.msgBox("It will take some time to send all these emails. There are more than 25 rows, so we're using the slower mode, to send as many as possible. See the Instructions and Settings sheet for details.");

  ScriptProperties.setProperty('newLine',"<br><br>");
  settingsDataRange=setProperties();
  var mergeDataValues=getMergeDataValues();
  var arrayOfTags=mergeDataValues[0]; //gets the first row


  //run through the remaining rows
  for (i=1; i<mergeDataValues.length; i++) { //loops through the rows in the merge sheet. Misses 0, which is column headings
    try {
      var thisEmailAddress=mergeDataValues[i][2];
      var thisEmailText=ScriptProperties.getProperty('genericEmailText');
      var thisEmailSubject=ScriptProperties.getProperty('subject');
      var arrayOfValues=mergeDataValues[i];
      for (j=1; j<arrayOfTags.length; j++) { //loops through the columns
        var replaceData=arrayOfValues[j];      
        var tag=ScriptProperties.getProperty('before')+arrayOfTags[j]+ScriptProperties.getProperty('after');
        while (thisEmailText.search(tag)>=0) { //loop through, to ensure we replace every occurence of "tag"
          thisEmailText=thisEmailText.replace(tag,arrayOfValues[j]);
          thisEmailSubject=thisEmailSubject.replace(tag,arrayOfValues[j]);
        }
      }
      thisEmailText=thisEmailText.replace(/\n/g,"<br>"); //ensure any linebreaks from Google doc are carried to the HTML version. The /g means all occurences.

      //create a plain text version, by swapping <br> for \n, and stripping any other HTML tags
      var plainEmailText=thisEmailText.replace(/<br>/g,"\n");
      plainEmailText=stripHTML(plainEmailText); 
      var attachmentFiles = [];
      var ID = sheet.getRange(i+1,5).getValue();
      Logger.log(ID);
      var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(ID);
      attachmentFiles.push(pdf);
      var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:thisEmailText, name:ScriptProperties.getProperty('senderName'), replyTo:ScriptProperties.getProperty('replyTo'), attachments:attachmentFiles };

      MailApp.sendEmail(thisEmailAddress,thisEmailSubject, plainEmailText, advancedArgs);
      var range=sheet.getRange(i+1,1);
      ...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. i added the attacment column and edited the script but after the script has run its course the status bar in the mailMerge sheet says Failed and no mail was sent. i tried different  ID.s

Comment: Would be nice if you could send up too 5-6 different attachments too the same email address.